# Convert Ethereum or Bitcoin address to Polkadot or Substrate-based address

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, substrate

I would like to convert user's Ethereum address for example(0xc5D3a7d27DbDe23A7FC5E53F1a6f17F38C03194F) to substrate based address in this case(5DXoin5qNbzKt88CxDtx86vmaCxhxYzEfEWXahTvwgYMf4Gq). I manage to do it via subkey although it is based on the mnemonic, is it possible for me to convert any public address in any network to substrate-based address? The reason to do this is to to allow users with existing address and infrastructure such as Metamask or Trezor can use Polkadot and other substrate-based chain.

Comment: When you "convert" do you just use the same public key for both chains or something else? I know that Ethereum public address is not a full public key, only part of it, making it not contain enough data to simply remap

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa I would assume that I dont since I only have the address but it is possible for users to manually export their full private key?

Comment: Metamask integrations are coming. Legder is live, and AFAIK trezor cannot support the key format without major work that no one is doing at the moment (that I know of) 

What you want to do is derive a public key from a shared seed or at least a shared private key.subkey is the tool for you, yes :)

Comment: Users can export their seed, BUT WITH NOTE that they *must* know what they are doing with regards to exposing that seed on a new application. For example, if you wanted to, you could use the same 12 words in metamask now, or any BIP32/39/42 compliment algorithm to get a valid public key from it.

Comment: @NukeManDan so are you saying at this moment, there is no way for me to convert ethereum public address to polkadot and vice versa without users using their private key?

Comment: @AfeezAziz sorry for the delay - on further thought on your proposed use case, I suggest you are after the wrong things here. If you are after using MM and Trezor with Ethereum signing operations to interact with a generic substrate node, you are not going to be able to. I suggest you look at https://moonbeam.network/ for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

MetaMask is implementing a new feature called snaps: ([Documentation](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/snaps.html)).

Once this functionality becomes standard, it would become trivial to make a snap that manages keychains for Polkadot. For example, here is the FileCoin snap: https://github.com/Chainsafe/filsnap/